# C#, how do I use a dateTimePicker's value on if statements?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

The work I'm doing consists on finding out one's astral sign, so I put a dateTimePicker to select the date of birth, but now I'm not sure how I will get the data from that dateTimePicker to check which sign is it...

Like for example, from january first to february 14th you are this sign, from this to that you're... you know what I mean.

Comment: Err, the date picker control doesn't have this information. You'll have to write your own algorithm to figure out the sign or use some third-party component to do it. Unless of course you just meant how to get the date value itself, which you can do by accessing the `Value` property.

Comment: yea I just wanted to know how to get the value from the datetimepicker, thank you ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not concerned about the year. You just need the month and day values:

```
DateTimePicker dtp = new DateTimePicker();

int month = dtp.Value.Month;
int day = dtp.Value.Day;
```

Then, you can do `if-else` statements around the various astral signs:

```
if (month >= 3 && day >= 20 && month < 4 && day <21 )
{
    return AstralSign.Aries;
}
else if (/* some other sign */)
{
    // ...
}
```

You can create an `enum` for the signs as well:

```
enum AstralSign
{
   ...
   Aries
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`DateTimePicker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z1b6077x.aspx) has a property [`Value`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.value.aspx). This contains the selected date by the user.

If you like to get informed when the user made his selection, simply subscribe to the [`ValueChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.valuechanged.aspx) property.

Afterwards simply compare if the the given date falls within the range of any astral sign.

To get the astral sign i would built up a nested dictionary `Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, AstralSign>>` which could then be access by

```
selectedSign = astralSigns[pickedDate.Month][pickedDate.Day];
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in functionality in `DateTimePicker` for achieving this.  You will have to either go for `if-else` approach or a `switch` statement to find out which sign a particular date belongs to..

Comment: `if-else` is good. But if you go with `switch`, you'll have to play around with the values because it accepts only `nullable` types.

Answer (score 1):

If your DateTimePicker was called dateTimePicker, you could do it like this:

```
DateTime pickedDate = new DateTime(dateTimePicker.Value.Year, dateTimePicker.Value.Month, dateTimePicker.Value.Day);
```

And then you could use pickedDate as you want.

Comment: `dateTimePicker.Value` is already of type `DateTime`. What am I missing?

Comment: Sorry, in my code I was combining it with the time from a time picker, and so I had to create a new DateTime to include both. When I answered I just cut out the time bits but should have just used dateTimePicker.Value like you said.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing in built in for Zodiac signs , so i would recommend you building your own list for the Zodiac signs.

Comparing a date falls in which zodia part you can go along with `DayOfYear` part of the `Datetime value` selected in the `DatePicker` (`dateTimePicker1.Value`)

So 0 to 46 could be your first zodiac and compare this with the `DayOfYear` part and you will have your Zodiac sign (else year would be a problem while comparing `DateTime` objects)